# Angular2 date pipe automatically adding timezone to date

Tags: angular, typescript, date-pipe

I have a date string, like this `1987-06-15T00:00:00.000Z`, when I am added date pipe on it the date is showing a different date like `Jun 14, 1987` in American time zone, but in India, it's showing correct.

```
<div>{{'1987-06-15T00:00:00.000Z' | date}}</div>
```

Comment: You want output like `dd/MM/yyyy` ?

Comment: You can specify format in date pipe. If you are not happy with available date pipe formats, you can create and register your own pipe in the module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is worked for me

```
<div>{{date_of_birth.split("T")[0] | date}}</div>
```

Comment: Cleaner/slower/better/worse?  <div>{{date_of_birth | splice: 0:10 | date}}</div>

Answer (score 4):

The string `1987-06-15T00:00:00.000Z` represents different dates in different browser time zones.

## Fix

If you don't want to change the date based on time zone, just use string parsing (e.g. `substr`) and not date parsing.

Comment: Is there is any option in date pipe?

Comment: Nope. It is meant to represent a given date in the user's time zone.

Comment: From the Source code:
WARNINGS:

- this pipe uses the Internationalization API. Therefore it is only reliable in Chrome and Opera browsers.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.3/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts#L16-L143