# Angular date pipe subtracts a day from the actual date value

Tags: angular6, angular-pipe

I am not sure If I need to add anything here. I have a table with a date column. When the date column gets processed through the Angular date pipe, just to change the format to display, it subtracts a day from the actual date. I checked it without adding the date pipe, I get the actual date. What could be wrong?

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'pending'" style="color:#367db9">
   {{ workOrder.postDate | date: 'MMM d, y'}}
</div>
```

Comment: I also have this issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the custom format?

```
{{ workOrder.postDate | date: 'MMM d, y'}}
```

should be the same result as

```
{{ workOrder.postDate | date }}
```

and the same as

```
{{workOrder.postDate | date:'mediumDate'}}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/Scotty3/bdmqxr5y/4757/

and https://next.angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

If not you'll need to check your source date variable.

Comment: Hello @scotty3, I tried your code, it is still the same way.

Comment: @Sumchans what is the raw value of workOrder.postDate? try putting it into the jsfiddle I linked and see what you get.

Comment: Wow that looks strange, I tried the raw value which I get from the server, it works perfectly on the jsFiddle, then what would be wrong with my code then. Here is the raw value : 2018-06-11 00:00:00

Comment: Found a fix for now from another post {{ workOrder.postDate.split("T")[0] | momentDatePipe}} https://stackoverflow.com/a/45582738/3826733